# Create a view based on node reference field

Tags: 7, nodes, views

There are two content types Gallery and Image. Image has node reference field (node reference from url). Gallery doesn't have any node reference fields.

By using views I can show all related images on a gallery page (I use node reference field "field_pers_gallery" as a contextual filter).

At the same time I need to create a view to show all images related to one gallery (all images have the same value in field field_pers_gallery) on a page of every image. I would like to create a view that looks like Flickr  image page with related images. I have the problem with it because I cannot choose the right contextual filter to create the view as I want.

I tried the following examples but nothing helped me, I cannot understand why.

- http://drupal.org/node/370227#comment-4364810
- http://drupal.org/node/370227#comment-5699610
- [How can I build a view that shows other nodes that reference the same node the current node references?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12104/how-can-i-build-a-view-that-shows-other-nodes-that-reference-the-same-node-the-c)

Could anybody help me with any advices?

Comment: Are you creating a relationship for the node reference?

Comment: Yes, I choosed field_pers_gallery as a relationship. If I chose Node:nid as context filter and don't use relationship my view show me only one image that is a current image page is. If I use relationship in context filter my view doesn't show me anything

Answer (score 2):

I think here is a simple solution just add that the node reference field (field_pers_gallery) to contextual filter then all nodes (Images) which have same value in that field can be displayed on a page.

Comment: That one is the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to display other nodes that reference the same node that the current node references. No need for relationships, just follow these steps:

1. Make sure you're filtering the view by the content type you want to view a list of, not the one you're trying to reference.
2. Add a contextual filter using the entity reference field.
3. For the entity reference field, choose to provide a default value in PHP **¹**.
4. Adapt the following code to your field names **²** and save the contextual filter:

   $node = menu_get_object();
   $referenced_node = $node->field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['target_id'];
   return $referenced_node;
5. Save the view and check it out.

**¹Disclaimer:** PHP should never be used in the UI due to concerns with security, performance, & lack of version control. As a result, the *proper* way to implement this solution involves writing your own simple module that creates a block that passes the argument into the view as you render it in the block. I'm still including this because whether people ignore this warning or use it to write a module, hopefully it helped.

**²** Not sure what your field names are? Install and enable the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and visit a node. Click the 'devel' tab and navigate through the list to find your desired entity reference field.

Comment: Is there any need to use PHP code? Basing on what the OP wrote under [SOLVED](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/46050/5) (the part I am going to delete), there is no need to use PHP code.

Comment: This is the only solution I was able to find after trying several different suggestions. It was the only thing that worked for me, but YMMV.

Comment: If you are using References module, then you need to adjust the code as the field structure is different.

Comment: This example isn't using the References module - so no worries there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about node reference, but since another answer proposes [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) for the reference field(s) I will piggyback on that suggestion.

With Entity references in place, you'll be able to add "reverse references" within the relationship builder in the Views admin UI. These will read as

> "Entity Reference: **Referencing entity**"

(as opposed to **Referenced entity**)...

Here's what these look like:

[image]

It takes a bit of getting used to, maybe some eye strain, to establish the reverse reference you're looking for. Once working, I find it helps to give it a meaningful administrative label, like "Nodes pointing here" or, in your case "Appearing in [Galleries]:" or something similar.